# Is it possible to unit test CallActivityWithRetryAsync and reproduce retries?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have read the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-unit-testing) but it doesn't mention `CallActivityWithRetryAsync`.

My `IDurableOrchestrationContext` is mocked for the call I'm making:

```cs
mockContext.Setup(c => c.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(nameof(SerialiseXml), It.IsAny<RetryOptions>(),
                It.IsAny<InboundOrchestrationData>()))
            .ThrowsAsync(new IOException());
```

and I can put a breakpoint at the calling point:

```
try
{
    await context.CallActivityWithRetryAsync("SerialiseXml",
        new RetryOptions(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 3), data);    // breakpoint
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.LogError("Problem serialising xml.");
}
```

but my code only ever breaks here once when I would expect it to break three times according to the RetryOptions.

If I pass in a `Mock<ILogger<Class>>` and check the invocations there is also only one. I have also configured my mock using `SetupSequence()` and multiple `.ThrowsAsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do mind that if you start mocking

```cs
mockContext.Setup(c => c.CallActivityWithRetryAsync(nameof(SerialiseXml), It.IsAny<RetryOptions>(),
                It.IsAny<InboundOrchestrationData>()))
            .ThrowsAsync(new IOException());
```

there won't be any retries performed at all since it is mocked. There is no real implementation that is executed.

Inside the implementation of `CallActivityWithRetryAsync` there will be a retry of the specified activity call in case of a retryable failure. Only after all retry attempts have failed an exception will bubble up to your code. So I ever expect just one call to `CallActivityWithRetryAsync`.

Your exception handling code will also be just called once, and only when all retries have failed or there is another reason for the call to fail.

The implementation of `CallActivityWithRetryAsync` will look like this (simplified):

```cs
async Task<int> CallActivityWithRetryAsync(string activity, RetryOptions retryOptions)
{
    int attempts = 1;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            return await CallActivity(activity);
        }
        catch
        {
            ++attempts;
            if (attempts > retryOptions.RetryCount)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given this pseudocode you can easily see why the breakpoint hits only one.